# Inheritance of private members

Tags: c++, inheritance

When asked if private members of class B are inherited by D, a class derived from B, people emphatically say: yes they are inherited but not accessible directly, only indirectly for instance via public methods in the base class. OK, but what is the *difference* between not being inherited and not being directly accessible? For instance class X (NOT derived from B) also has access to private members of B via public methods of B, even though X doesn't inherit anything from B. 
what is the difference between 
1) not being inherited and 
2) being inherited and not being directly accessible.
what is not clear?

Comment: You can read more about accessibility at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access.

Comment: nice, except that my question is not about access, it's about the meaning of being inherited

Comment: You may want to (a) update the question with relevant code and more direct questions, or (b) create a new question with relevant code and more direct questions.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the class layout.

```
struct B {
    private: char buf[1024];
};

struct D : B { };
```

Here, `sizeof(D)` >= `sizeof(B)`. It's still *there*, i.e. it's clearly inherited.

Answer (score 1):

If the base class has virtual functions that can be overriden by the derived class, clearly this is an important difference to a class having access to a base class instance but not inheriting from it:

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {}

    int get_a() const
    {
        do_something();
        return a;
    }

    virtual void do_something() const
    {
        std::cout << "In B\n";
    }

private:
    int a{};
};

class D : public B
{
    virtual void do_something() const
    {
        std::cout << "In D\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.get_a();
}
```

If the base class does not have any virtual functions, then the usefulness of inheriting from it is less clear. In fact, it is perhaps best not to inherit from it (at least publicly) as the lack of a virtual destructor could cause some problems, and it should be made a member variable instead.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my post. The question is: are private data members inherited? For the sake of argument, let's say they were not (but would still be indirectly accessible via mutators / accessors). What would be different then?

Comment: @JKay I don't understand. If private members were not inherited, where would the accessors go to get the data?

Comment: Accessors (public methods) that are members of Base have access to private data members (of Base).

Comment: @JKay Yes but these data members need to be stored somewhere. Either a derived object has them in its memory layout, or not.

Comment: Again, if class X is NOT derived from base B, but has access to private members of B via public accessors, where are those members stored? Why doesn't your answer to this question not apply also to D derived from B?

Comment: @JKay Then the members are stored wherever your B object is stored. Either you inherit from it, it is a member variable, or it declared outside the class and passed to it.